# Standard notation for tuples with named entries?

Tags: notation

Mostly I've seen people use the following notation: If $s=(3,\emptyset, i)$ is some arbitrary tuple, then we have $s_1=3, s_2=\emptyset$ and so forth. However, sometimes in a tuple, the different entries have distinct ideas belonging to them and it makes sense to give them names instead, meaning, to write $s_n=3,s_{set}=\emptyset,s_c=i$ instead of $s_1=3, s_2=\emptyset$. I'm tempted to write something like $s\in (n\in \mathbb N)\times (set \in \mathcal P(N))\times (c\in \mathbb C)$, so that $s_n=3,s_{set}=\emptyset,s_c=i$. **Is there a standard notation along these lines?**

Comment: You could write $s=(3,\emptyset,i)\in\Bbb N\times \mathcal P(\mathbb N)\times \mathbb C$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I maybe should rephrase the question.

Comment: I'm not sure @J.W.Tanner was providing an answer in a comment, so much as correcting the nonstandard "$(n\in\mathbb N)\times(set\in\mathcal{P}(N))\times(c\in\mathbb C)$". Though I'm not sure since the use of the word "could" is suggestive.

Comment: I don't think there's anything "standard" on this matter, because I can't see the usefulness of having tuples with items from different sets in them.

Comment: @K.defaoite A pointed space is an example. There are many examples.